# How to pass this variable of checkbox from java method to JavaScript method using this variable of checkbox, but i am not getting correct output

Tags: javascript, java, html, checkbox

I need to pass checkbox Boolean value(True or False) from below java method to java script function.

Java Method::

```
M1() {
  generatedXML.append("<div id=checkboxes> ");
  generatedXML.append("<input type=checkbox ");
  generatedXML.append(" onchange=\"setValue('");
  generatedXML.append(obj);
  generatedXML.append("','");
  generatedXML.append('this');
  generatedXML.append("');\"");
}
```

JavaScript function::

```
function setValue(obj,refr) 
{
  alert(refr.checked); // i think it will alert true or false??
  //Need Boolean value of checkbox 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add an id attribute to the checkbox and in the javascript access the checkbox itself by its own id. Something like

```
document.getElementById('checkIdHere');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your checkbox with an ID and in `onchange` function access checkbox with that id or you can pass the instance of checkbox to `onchange` function and directly access the value of checkbox.

```
var value = document.getElementById("chkTest").checked
```

And if you want to access value without `id` than pass `this` to `onchange` function from java like (syntax may not be correct please ignore as i don have editor for this)

```
generatedXML.append(" onchange=\"setValue('");
generatedXML.append(obj);
generatedXML.append("','");
generatedXML.append(path);
generatedXML.append("',this);
generatedXML.append(");\"");
```

And in javascript do this

```
function setValue(obj,path,chkBox) {
var value = chkBox.checked;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i am facing  syntax problem i.e how to pass  'this'  from this method.   i am trying to pass like generatedXML.append(this);  , but in javascript i am getting undefined value.

Comment: have you changed the javascript function as well ?

Comment: //generatedXML.append(this); 


function setValue(obj,path,refr)
{
 alert(refr.checked); // i think it will alert true or false

}

Comment: Ok may be `this` is being used of java try to surround it in single qoutes

Comment: you mean like this?     generatedXML.append('this');

Comment: but it is showing error in eclipse  i.e invalid character constant.

Comment: try like `generatedXML.append("'this'")`;

Comment: even it is not going into javascript method with   ("'this'");  syntax.

Comment: Assign an id to checkbox and access value by id